# Fetch corresponding value of a drop downlist

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I want to fetch the corresponding value of my dropdown the image below shows the form and the database. the table was inside the javascript and Iam having a dificult time in figuring out this problem. please help me how to solve this problem... Thank you very much in advance...

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrsD3.jpg)

[forms entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Sfun.jpg)

My Controller

```
function getFeetypeEndDate() {
    $feetype_id = $this->input->get('feety_id[]');
    $data = $this->feegroup_model->getFeetypeByEndDate($feetype_id);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

My Model

```
 public function get($id = null) {
    $this->db->select()->from('feetype');
    $this->db->where('is_system', 0);
    if ($id != null) {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
    } else {
        $this->db->order_by('id');
    }
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($id != null) {
        return $query->row_array();
    } else {
        return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

My Javascript in the View Section

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function (){
            $("body").on('click', '.btn-add-more', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var amount = $("#amount").val();
        var penalty = $("#penalty").val();
        var $sr = ($(".jdr1").length + 1);
        var rowid = Math.random();
        var $html = '<tr class="jdr1" id="' + rowid + '">' +
                '<td><span class="btn btn-sm btn-default">' + $sr + '</span><input type="hidden" name="count[]" value="'+Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1)+'"></td>' +
                '<td><select id="feetype_id[]" name="feetype_id[]" class="form-control" >' + 
                '<?php foreach ($feetypeList as $feetype) { ?>' +
                ' <option value="<?php echo $feetype['id'] ?>" ' +
                '<?php if (set_value('feetype_id[]') == $feetype['id']) { echo "selected =selected"; } ?>><?php echo $feetype['type'] ?></option> <?php $count++; } ?> </select></td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" id="startDate" name="startDate" value="<?php echo date($this->customlib->getSchoolDateFormat($feetype->start_date), $this->customlib->dateyyyymmddTodateformat($feetype->start_date)); ?>" placeholder="Start Date" class="form-control input-sm"/></td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" id="endDate" name="endDate" value="<?php echo date($this->customlib->getSchoolDateFormat($feetype->end_date), $this->customlib->dateyyyymmddTodateformat($feetype->end_date)); ?>" placeholder="End Date" class="form-control input-sm"/></td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" name="amount_td[]" placeholder="Amount" class="form-control input-sm" value="'+amount+'"></td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" name="penalty_td" placeholder="Penalty" class="form-control input-sm" value="'+penalty+'"></td>' +
                '</tr>';
        $("#table-details").append($html);

    });
    $("body").on('click', '.btn-remove-detail-row', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if($("#table-details tr:last-child").attr('id') != 'row1'){
            $("#table-details tr:last-child").remove();
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: @RP can you show us your an error? please check your console, are you using ajax on add More button?

Comment: the error is that the starting date and end date dont fetch as in the image below it is always show the default date of 01/01/1970 the date is in the same table as the month

Comment: But your question is related to drop down list [Month]

Comment: yes it is related please view the 2 attached images I want to automatically fetch the starting date and the end date in the inputbox when you select the month(feetype) that is my problem